# Does Simulink have a Compare to Constant block with the constant defined outside the block?

Tags: simulink, logical-operators

Consider Simulink's `Compare to constant` block.

The constant to which you are comparing the input signal, has to be set in the *Function block parameters* window (double click on the block). Is there an other block that compares two input signals, namely the previously mentioned input signal and a constant (in this case 5)? Because of the fact that the constant is no longer a parameter but an external signal, this would be useful to combine with a `from` block.

[image]

Or does this alternative block not exist because you could actually check if the difference between two signals is smaller than or equal to a constant with a `compare to zero` block?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Relational Operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/relationaloperator.html) block...

[image]